# Angular 1:Build dropdown box dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular 1,so I am stuck with building a dropdown box dynamically using angular.

Below is my code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
```

I have created an onchange function getTypeName() and have passed the parameters using get method and retrieved the result as json .

```
 $scope.getTypeName = function (type) {
   $http.get('get-type-name', 
      { params: 
          {
            type: type
          }
      }).then(
          function(response){
            var data = response.data; 
            for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                //code to build dropdown 
            }
          },
      );
  }
});
```

Below is my response,

```
[
  {"id":"001","name":"ABC"},                  
  {"id":"002","name":"DEF"},    
  {"id":"003","name":"GHI"}
]
```

I want to build a dropdown box using this response within the get method function success using for loop.Please provide a solution to solve this out.

Comment: `<select ng-model="selectedResponse" ng-options="x.name for x in data"></select>`

Comment: I want to build up the dropdown within loop..How will i do it?

Comment: You don't need `loop` at all, but if you insist: `$scope.data = []; for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) $scope.data.push(data[i]);` instead of simple: `$scope.data = data;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
$scope.yourOptions = [];
$scope.getTypeName = function (type) {$http.get('get-type-name', 

  { params: 
      {
        type: type
      }
  }).then(
      function(response){
        var data = response.data; 
        $scope.yourOptions = data;
      },
  );
```

}
});

in html,

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="whatever"  >
<option ng-repeat="x in yourOptions " value="{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you do like this
in app.js

```
$scope.getTypeName = function (type) {
   $http.get('get-type-name', 
      { params: 
          {
            type: type
          }
      }).then(
          function(response){
            $scope.data = response.data; 

          },
      );
  }
});
```

in your html

```
 <select id="ddl" model="ddldata" typeof="text"required>
      <option data-ng-repeat="ProjectName in data" value="{{ProjectName.id}}" ng-bind={{ProjectName.name}}">
  </select>
```

Comment: check this and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of dynamically populating select options from an http get https://plnkr.co/edit/7PS7LBBNZA2cNzMorrB9?p=preview

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
  <option ng-repeat="o in options">{{o.name}}</option>
</select>

$scope.getTypeName = function() {
 $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(
  function(result) {
    $scope.options = result.data;
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
};
```